# Negation in z3 datalog for expressing optimality

Tags: z3, datalog

I use `Z3` with `:fixedpoint.engine` set to `datalog`.
I have an enumerated filter relation `(f pos min max)`. Let us say that we have `(f #x10 #x100000 #x200000)`, `(f #x20 #x150000 #x200000)` and `(f #x20 #x300000 #x500000)`.

For a given `x`, I search the greatest `pos` such that `(f pos min max)` and `min <= x <= max` *(Here I use intervals but filters can be arbitrarily complex)*. Priority (sort `t`) and values (sort `s`) are BitVectors but `x`, `min` and `max` are on a rather large space *(eg. 24 bits)*.

```
; configuration 
(set-option :fixedpoint.engine datalog)
; sorts
(define-sort s () (_ BitVec 24))
(define-sort t () (_ BitVec 8))
; Relations
(declare-rel f (t s s))
(declare-rel match (t s))
(declare-rel better (t s))
(declare-rel best (t s))
(declare-rel a (t))
(declare-rel b ())
(declare-rel c ())
(declare-var x s)
(declare-var xmin s)
(declare-var xmax s)
(declare-var p t)
(declare-var q t)
; Facts (EDB)
(rule (f #x10 #x100000 #x200000))
(rule (f #x20 #x150000 #x200000))
(rule (f #x20 #x300000 #x500000))
; Rules
(rule (=> (and (f p xmin xmax) (bvule xmin x) (bvule x xmax))
          (match p x)))
(rule (=> (and (match q x) (bvugt q p))
          (better p x)))
(rule (=> (and (match p x) (not (better p x)))
          (best p x)))
; Queries
(rule (=> (match p #x170000) (a p)))
(rule (=> (better #x10 #x170000) b))
(rule (=> (best #x10 #x170000) c))
; output: sat
; (or (= (:var 0) #x20) (= (:var 0) #x10))
(query (a p) :print-answer true)
; output: sat
(query b)
; Output 'WARNING: creating large table of size 16777216 for relation better' and fails
(query c)
```

- `(match p x)` codes the fact that a filter at priority `p` filters `x`.
- `(better p x)` if a rule with a better priority than `p` filters `x`.
- `(best p x)` codes that the best filter matching `x` has priority `p`.

If I query `(match p #x170000)`, I quickly get `#x10` and `#x20`. If I ask  `(better #x10 #x170000)` I quickly get 
an answer same for priority `#20`. But the query on `(best p #x170000)` fails to execute in reasonable time and reasonable space.

It seems that `(not (better p x))` is computed independently of `(match p x)` and so is represented by a very large table (the possible values of `x` are not forwarded). In some cases I can restrict `x` by some tricks in better *(sometimes I know that I am only interested by `x` that explicitly appear in other relations)* so that the space is reduced but this is not a real generic solutions and sometimes I am stuck.

How should I rephrase the problem or which options should I use to avoid this problem ?

Comment: May I know why the question was downvoted ? The example is contrived but  it tries to capture the essence of "match with" where one takes the first filter in a programming language, or in a firewall, or in a routing table (the priority would be the length of the prefix). f and match are usually more complex.

Comment: Questions by new users end up being reviewed by general SO members who might not have enough field expertise to understand it and judge it fairly, so downvotes are a possibility. Other than the fact that the problem description does not include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I think it's a good question. However, I am not sure whether it can be given a specific answer as it is. Woul it be possible for you to add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I added all the declarations and queries so that the example can be run as `z3 test.smt2`.

Answer (score 1):

Z3's default Datalog tables are over concrete values, so if you use large bit-vectors, Z3 may end-up creating huge tables.
You can try a simpler table data-structure, that supports fewer operations but it's sparse (uses "don't care" bits).
You can try it out with: z3 fixedpoint.engine=datalog fixedpoint.datalog.default_relation=doc file.smt2

Comment: Thank you, it is a relation type I did not try. Unfortunately it seems doc does not support bitvector comparison (fails on `bvule`) at least with a negation (first two queries are fine). I have tried to adapt it to what I thought would be a simpler case with more classical bit arithmetic (filter defined by prefix and mask, match if `x & mask = prefix` and priority to the longest mask) but even then I get *Guard expression is not handled* on expressions containing `=`, `bvor` and `bvnot`. What are the operations supported by `doc` and in which context ?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/muz/rel/udoc_relation.cpp#L800
It should be straightforward to add support for bvor and similar operations though..